# Setting framebuffer alpha value via SDL

Tags: sdl, embedded-linux

I'm working on a graphics application on an embedded linux system. The app uses SDL, which is using /dev/fb0. This device has a 4 byte pixel format for red, green, blue and alpha. The alpha value is used to blend /dev/fb0 with a motion video plane.

The /dev/fb0 alpha value works as specified when I write to /dev/fb0 directly.

Unfortunately when I call the SDL functions the alpha value in /dev/fb0 is set to zero. (For example calling boxRGBA to set a rectangle white results in each framebuffer pixel in the rectangle being set to 0xFFFFFF00.)

Is there a way of making SDL set the alpha values in /dev/fb0 to my desired values?

There's a lot of SDL documentation on alpha, but this seems to relate to SDL operations and not the alpha value in the final framebuffer output.

*edit* fbset output:

```
mode "1360x768-60"
    # D: 85.507 MHz, H: 47.716 kHz, V: 60.020 Hz
    geometry 1360 768 1360 768 32
    timings 11695 256 64 18 3 112 6
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24
endmode
```

*edit* SDL initialisation and test rectangle fill (note this is SDL 1.2)

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
m_screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(0, 0, 0, SDL_FULLSCREEN | SDL_HWSURFACE);
SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);
SDL_FillRect(m_screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGBA(m_screen->format, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0xFF));
SDL_Flip(m_screen);
```

*edit* debugging shows that the SDL_Surface returned by SDL_SetVideoMode() has a SDL_PixelFormat with no alpha, i.e. Amask is 0, Ashift is 0 and Aloss is 8.

*edit* explicitly setting the alpha channel on the SDL_Surface gives the correct results. But the code looks unsatisfactory: I'm setting fields marked for internal use only:

```
m_screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(0, 0, 0, SDL_FULLSCREEN | SDL_HWSURFACE);
m_screen->format->Amask = 0xFF000000;
m_screen->format->Ashift = 24;
m_screen->format->Aloss = 0;
```

Comment: Please show the source of the surface/texture creation and of the SDL initialization. Maybe you didnt set alpha support for SDL.

Comment: @Nidhoegger: I've added this to my question

Comment: You know that the rect you fill is with Alpha set to 255, so not transclurent at all. Try: SDL_FillRect(m_screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGBA(m_screen->format, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80)); which should give you an alpha rect. If that fails, debug into your application an look in the m_screen->format rect to see, if it has actually an alpha channel

Comment: @Nidhoegger: I want the rectangle to be opaque hence the 255, but the final framebuffer alpha is set to 0. Since the alpha channel on /dev/fb0  is WRT another video plane, it won't work as an alpha channel for operations confined to /dev/fb0, so maybe SDL won't see it. I'll set up a debug build and report back.

Comment: I have the feeling that the result is undefined by SDL.  You might look under the hood and see what it does in the particular backend that you're using...